# Dynamic scaling & brush off composite charts dc js

Tags: javascript, dynamic, charts, dc.js

I have a composite chart using dc js (line and bar chart)

However, the scales are not dynamically changing as is the case while using singular bar/line dc charts

I have made 5 ticks for both the y-axis (secondary and primary both) for clarity, but I want the **scales and tickintervals of Y-Axis** to change dynamically depending on values calculated.

Code:

```
//Composite chart to show 2 metrics
    chart3
    .width(500) // (optional) define chart width, :default = 200
    .height(200) // (optional) define chart height, :default = 200
    .transitionDuration(500) // (optional) define chart transition duration, :default = 500
    // (optional) define margins
    .margins({top: 30, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 40})
    .dimension(dateDimension) // set dimension
    //.group(rechfreqGroup) // set group
    // (optional) whether chart should rescale y axis to fit data, :default = false
    .elasticY(true)
    // (optional) when elasticY is on whether padding should be applied to y axis domain, :default=0
    .yAxisPadding(100)
    // (optional) whether chart should rescale x axis to fit data, :default = false
    //.elasticX(true)
    // (optional) when elasticX is on whether padding should be applied to x axis domain, :default=0
    .xAxisPadding(500)
    // define x scale
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["DURING","POST1"]))
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    //.renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    //.renderVerticalGridLines(true)
    .legend(dc.legend().x(200).y(5).itemHeight(10).gap(3))
    .title(function(d) { return "Revenue : "  + d3.round(d.value.rechtotal/d.value.new_count,2) + " Frequency : " + 
    d3.round(d.value.rechfreq/d.value.new_count,2) ; })
    .yAxisLabel("Revenue (in $)")
    .rightYAxisLabel("Frequency")
    .brushOn(false)
    // compose sub charts, currently composite chart only supports line chart & bar chart
    ._rangeBandPadding(1) //workaround to fix visual stuff (dc js issues)
    .compose([

        dc.barChart(chart3).group(rechrevGroup,"Average Revenue").gap(10).centerBar(true).xUnits(function(){return 10;}).valueAccessor(function (p) {
        return (p.value.rechtotal / p.value.new_count) ; 
        //return p.value.count > 0 ? p.value.rechtotal / p.value.new_count : 0;
        }),
        // you can even include stacked bar chart or line chart in a composite chart
        dc.lineChart(chart3).group(rechfreqGroup,"Average Frequency").brushOn(false).useRightYAxis(true).colors('#000000').valueAccessor(function (p) {
        return (p.value.rechfreq / p.value.new_count) ;
        })
    ])
    .yAxis().ticks(5);

    chart3.rightYAxis().ticks(5);
```

Is it possible to make the scaling dynamic *(Y- axis here)* as per the values calculated? 
If not, can I atleast set the tickValues etc?

Any approach/suggestions on dynamic scaling and/or alternatives would be highly appreciated

**UPDATE**

Created a fiddle with my exact same code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vct0dzou/34/)

2 issues with this :

1. Dynamic scaling of chart works perfectly with/without elasticY(true) in this fiddle. (Not working in my code and charts in the dashboard I'm building, though!) Why is this happening? Am I missing something/doing something fundamentally wrong here?
2. brushOn(false) is not working, the bars are clickable and they get selected in the fiddle ( In my project, they get selected and crossfilter filters all other graphs accordingly also) How do I turn the selection off? 
   Or, cross-filtering off for the particular graph?

Let me know if you have any solutions/approach to solve these issues

Comment: I assume it still does not work if you uncomment the `elasticX` above?

Comment: Nope, no difference. That actually, just overrides the ordinal domain order mentioned ( DURING, POST1). Any other ideas that can help here?

Comment: Oh, you are actually talking about the y-axis? Your question is somewhat unclear, please edit.

Comment: Yes apologies for the unclear question. I'm talking about y axis only (primary and secondary) -edited the question

Comment: @Gordon : Any ideas on how to solve this issue? Is dynamic scaling even feasible here? If not, can I atleast hard-code the tickIntervals in a composite chart in y-axis with estimated values? Do let me know whenever free.

Comment: It usually works, but perhaps you've run into some quirk. For example, there are a couple of composite charts in the [playground](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/play-ground.html) which work if one adds `elasticY`, and I also pasted the gainOrLoss chart into the [right axis example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/right-axis.html) and that worked. If you can [create a fiddle demonstrating the problem](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#issue-submission-guidelines) we should be able to track down what is going wrong.

Comment: @Gordon : Thanks for this, I created a fiddle and updated the question. Do look into it if you have time. It's quite weird that such a simple thing is not working.